# change subvariable in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

Is there a way to change a subvariable within a hash or a container in a FreeMarker template? For example, suppose I had:

```
{"name":"Bob", "city":"Detroit", "state":"OH"}
```

and I want to change the state to "MI". How would I go about doing that? I know about the [assign tag](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html), but the documentation says "Note that only top-level variables can be created/replaced". I am unsure as to whether this means subvariables can't be replaced with the assign tag, or subvariables can't be replaced by any means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out a simple way to do it:

```
<#assign hash = hash + {"state":"MI"}>
```

Comment: I accepted the answer. How can I close the thread? Why would I want to close the thread?